# Image attachments shows up as Links vBulletin 4.2.3 Patch Level 2

Tags: php, vbulletin

I just noticed that on my forum vBulletin 4.2.3 Patch Level 2, inline attachments now show as links. Here is an example of a post

http://www.jazzguitar.be/forum/announcements-suggestions-forum-help/57730-image-upload-not-working.html

I have found many posts about this problem and have checked the setting has been same as they are suggested.

I have checked the forum database the image inserting into the database but don't know why its showing link instead of the image .

Comment: And so, what is your question ?

Comment: my question is that how to show image thumbnail instead of showing the link? @Gille Q

Comment: anybody please suggest me ?